# how to restream saved rtp raw file?

Tags: gstreamer, wireshark, rtp

I need to simulate rtp stream coming from camera. It is important to use real data for test cases. I've already captured rtp stream using wireshark and following below instructions;

- Open the RTP capture file with Wireshark
- Select the proper UDP and force its decoding as RTP: Menu Analyze >>
  Decode As... RTP.
- Filter the G.729AB payload with display filter rtp.p_type==18.
- Menu Statistics(Wireshark 1.0) or Telephony >> RTP >> Show all
  streams. Select the one with G.729 of your interest, and press button
  Save, select one of '... Audio' options for single (forward or
  reverse) stream and then select 'Raw' formatted file.

I guess, [rtptools](https://www.cs.columbia.edu/irt/software/rtptools/) is using to replay rtp streams but the download link is not alive. How can I restream this saved rtp stream over udp to test?

***note**: gstreamer is used to handle rtp stream in the project.*

Answer (score 0):

There are several tools listed in the [Traffic generators](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/Tools#traffic-generators) section of the Wireshark [Tools](https://gitlab.com/wireshark/wireshark/-/wikis/Tools) wiki page that you might find useful for this purpose, a few among them:

- [Bit-Twist](http://bittwist.sourceforge.net/)
- [Packet Sender](https://packetsender.com/)
- [PlayCap](https://github.com/signal11/PlayCap)
- [Tcpreplay](http://tcpreplay.appneta.com/)

Of these, I've only personally used PlayCap, and it did the job for me, although if you're on the Windows platform, then I'm not sure if it works with [Npcap](https://nmap.org/npcap/), so you *might* need to install [WinPcap](https://www.winpcap.org/) instead.  Perhaps if Npcap is intalled in WinPcap-compatible mode it'll work.

Refer to the wiki page for the full list of known tools, keeping in mind that there very well could be other tools out there that just haven't been added to the list yet.